# Bluetooth module discover_devices doesn't work

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make a way for my raspberry to scan for devices around my home to see what traffic goes on around my house. The problem I'm having is that the script that I found on the github for pybluez works, but it doesn't find devices.

Thus, I instantly jump to command line and ran a bluetooth scan. The scan in command-line worked but the script keeps telling me that no devices are discovered. I've also tried downloading multiple bluetooth libraries that supports pybluez but still it doesn't work.

This is the script that I got it from.

````
```print "performing inquiry..."

```nearby_devices = discover_devices(lookup_names = True)

```print "found %d devices" % len(nearby_devices)

```for name, addr in nearby_devices:
         print " %s - %s" % (addr, name)



This is what I get when I run this script.

```found 0 devices
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm a new user...this script worked for me:

```
# file: inquiry.py
# auth: Albert Huang <albert@csail.mit.edu>
# desc: performs a simple device inquiry followed by a remote name request of
#       each discovered device
# $Id: inquiry.py 401 2006-05-05 19:07:48Z albert $
#

import bluetooth

print("performing inquiry...")

nearby_devices = bluetooth.discover_devices(
    duration=8, lookup_names=True, flush_cache=True, lookup_class=False)

print("found %d device(s)" % len(nearby_devices))

for addr, name in nearby_devices:
    try:
        print("  %s - %s" % (addr, name))
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("  %s - %s" % (addr, name.encode('utf-8', 'replace')))
```

The script finds my bluetooth mouse...MAC address partially hidden:

```
performing inquiry...
found 1 device(s)
98:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx - HP Bluetooth Mouse X4000b
[Finished in 10.575s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already solved your problem now. In my case it was the orientation of hardware (raspberry pi 3b). I think the bluetooth detection range varies upon the orientations.